# Polars UDF - returning and concatenating dataframes

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe that contains arguments to functions.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3],
        "bar": [6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ ham │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ f64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 6.0 ┆ a   │
│ 2   ┆ 7.0 ┆ b   │
│ 3   ┆ 8.0 ┆ c   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I want to apply a UDF to each row, performs a calculation, and then return a dataframe for each row. Each returned dataframe has the same schema, but a varying number of rows. The result should be a single dataframe.

e.g., simplified dummy example:

I tried this:

```py
def myUDF(row_tuple):
    foo, bar, ham = row_tuple
    result = pl.DataFrame({
        "a": foo + bar,
        "b": ham
    })

    return (result,)
```

```py
df.map_rows(myUDF)

shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────────┐
│ column_0       │
│ ---            │
│ object         │
╞════════════════╡
│ shape: (1, 2)  │
│ ┌─────┬─────┐  │
│ │ a …          │
│ shape: (1, 2)  │
│ ┌─────┬─────┐  │
│ │ a …          │
│ shape: (1, 2)  │
│ ┌──────┬─────┐ │
│ │ a…           │
└────────────────┘
```

This seems to work, but it means putting everything in a python dictionary. I'm worried about performance.

```py
def myUDF(row_tuple):
    foo, bar, ham = row_tuple
    result = pl.DataFrame({
        "a": foo + bar,
        "b": ham
    })

    return (result.to_dict(),)

df.map_rows(myUDF).unnest("column_0").explode("a", "b")

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b   │
│ ---  ┆ --- │
│ f64  ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╡
│ 7.0  ┆ a   │
│ 9.0  ┆ b   │
│ 11.0 ┆ c   │
└──────┴─────┘
```

Whats the "correct" way of doing this in polars?

### Follow-up information to respond to comments...

The actual operation is more involved and I thought including it in detail would detract from the specific guidance I was looking for. I oversimplified my example too much however causing confusion - my apologies. The important part I should have emphasised above is: "*...Each returned dataframe has the same schema, but a varying number of rows.*"

I hope its okay, but I've reworked the example to more faithfully mirror the operation I am trying to perform.

```py
reference_data = pl.DataFrame({
    "x": range(0, 10000000),
    "y": [chr(ord('a') + (i%26)) for i in range(0, 10000000)]
})

def myUDF(row_tuple):
    foo, bar, ham = row_tuple
    result = (
        reference_data
        .slice(foo, int(bar / 2))
        .with_columns(name=pl.lit(ham))
    )

    return (result.to_dict(),)
```

The result is:

```
df.map_rows(myUDF)

shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ column_0                          │
│ ---                               │
│ struct[3]                         │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ {[1, 2, 3],["b", "c", "d"],["a",… │
│ {[2, 3, 4],["c", "d", "e"],["b",… │
│ {[3, 4, … 6],["d", "e", … "g"],[… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

The result I would like is:

```py
df.map_rows(myUDF).unnest("column_0").explode(pl.all())

shape: (10, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ name │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ b   ┆ a    │
│ 2   ┆ c   ┆ a    │
│ 3   ┆ d   ┆ a    │
│ 2   ┆ c   ┆ b    │
│ 3   ┆ d   ┆ b    │
│ 4   ┆ e   ┆ b    │
│ 3   ┆ d   ┆ c    │
│ 4   ┆ e   ┆ c    │
│ 5   ┆ f   ┆ c    │
│ 6   ┆ g   ┆ c    │
└─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Comment: perf is going to be bad here...what's your expected output? is it really a `object` dtype column?

Comment: What is the real calculation you need to perform? Perhaps it can be done with Polars Expressions and avoid the need for a UDF in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @ignoring_gravity and @jqurious. I've attempted to clarify my question by adding an additional section above. In short, the `myUDF` function uses the row-tuple data to perform filtering, selection and computation on a second larger dataframe.

Comment: The updated example looks like you could explode int_ranges to use as a join key e.g. `df.with_row_index("row").with_columns(index = pl.int_ranges(pl.col("foo"), pl.col("foo") + pl.col("bar") // 2, dtype=pl.UInt32)).explode("index").join(reference_data.with_row_index(), on="index").sort("row")` - but depending on the exact task there may be a better approach. A UDF should not be needed for this type of thing though.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the "right" way is to not use `map_rows` at all but, not withstanding that, the output of the function you give to `map_rows` should return a tuple and it will construct a new df for you. You need not, and should not, construct a df within the function.

#### Option 1

keep with `map_rows` as its intended and rename columns manually

```
def myUDF(row_tuple):
    foo, bar, ham = row_tuple
    return (foo + bar, ham)

(
    df
    .map_rows(myUDF)
    .rename({f"column_{x}":y for x,y in enumerate(["a","b"])})
)
```

#### Option 2

keep with function returning a df but use `concat` and `iter_rows`

```
def myUDF(row_tuple):
    foo, bar, ham = row_tuple
    return pl.DataFrame({
        "a": foo + bar,
        "b": ham
    })
pl.concat([
    myUDF(x) for x in df.iter_rows()
])
```

#### Option *probably* red herring

Similar to option 2 but by making the return lazy, it does the computations in parallel. This only works for polars computations, any python execution will still be subject to the GIL and won't be parallel.

```
def myUDF(row_tuple):
    foo, bar, ham = row_tuple
    return (
        pl.select().lazy()
        .with_columns(a=pl.lit(foo) + pl.lit(bar), b=pl.lit(ham))
    )

pl.concat([
    myUDF(x) for x in df.iter_rows()
]).collect()
```

The last one is neat for the toy function because you get per row parallel execution but if your function can be made into expressions like this then you should just do it directly and not go through `iter_rows` or `map_rows`, that's why I called it a red herring. There are conceivably cases where rowwise parallelism is preferred to column based which is why I disclaimed red herring as only probably so.

Comment: Thanks for your write-up Dean MacGregor, I have not yet delved into lazy frames, but your red-herring example helps with some other code I had. In terms of my main question, `myUDF` needs to return a varying number of rows. I had oversimplified my example, so have added a follow-up section to my main question.

Comment: @polars_user It's discouraged to edit your question in a way where existing answers don't make sense in the new context. It's preferred that you just ask a new question.

Comment: I've re-edited the subheading to hopefully be more clear as "Follow-up information to respond to comments...
". I know its not ideal, but I thought it would be better to have the extended question in one thread as it was related, rather than ask a very similar question separately. I accept this is entirely my blunder in the way I asked the original question, and hope I didnt cause any offence.